# How to get a div value in js file from a ctp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have a hidden div in a ctp file.

```
<div id="UserId" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <?php 
        $UserId = $app['Auth']['User']['id'];
        echo $UserId;
    ?>
</div>
```

I need to get this $userId value in a .js file.

```
var user_id = $("#userId").val();
alert(user_id);
```

But I got empty value. Please help...

I tried with `var current_user_id = $("#userId").html();`
 but it shows the value in the center of the alert box and if i use that value in if condition, it does not return true for the condition.

For eg: say user_id value is 5.
A = 5

```
if (A == user_id){
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert(2);
}
```

It always returns 2.

Comment: Try .text() instead of .val() and parsing as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either get the value using `.innerHTML` or use an `<input />` tag to store your value for example:

```
$UserId = $app['Auth']['User']['id'];
echo "<input type = 'text' 
             id = 'UserId' 
             style = 'display: none;' 
             value = '" . $UserId . "' />";
```

you see `<div>` tags don't have values

Answer (score 0):

Check this for information on how to retrieve the users id in a view:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html

Additional information:

```
<?php debug($this->Session->read('Auth'); ?>
```